# How to add an object to a nested object, knowing the level of nesting to which the object should be added?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, lodash, nested-object

I have an object

```
const a = {
  b: {
    c: "new object",
    b: {
      c: "new object",
    }
  }
}
```

Here, the level of nesting for the key `b` is 2. I want to add another

```
 b: {
   c: "new object",
 }
```

to the last `b` i.e., 2nd level nested `b` which will make the object now have 3 level of nested `b`

The level of nesting is dynamic. It can be 0 as well. That means `const a = {}`

How can add an object to a nested object, knowing the level of nesting?

`eval()` is  out of option.

I'm currently doing it with lodash.

```js
let currentObj = a;
const thePath = ["b"];
// checking if "b" is present in the object and nesting if present
while (currentObj["b"]) {
  currentObj = currentObj["b"];
  thePath.push("b");
}
lodash.set(a, thePath, {
  c: "new object"
});
```

Is there any other approach? Can it be achieved with Object.assign somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the object and get finally the target object.

```js
const object = { b: { b: { l: 2 }, l: 1 }, l: 0 };
let temp = object,
    depth = 2;

while (depth--) temp = temp.b;

console.log(temp);

Object.assign(temp, { payload: 'foo' });

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Does the job. Thanks

Comment: I've combined my solution with yours. I've used "Object.assign" with "currentObj" and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Even without `Object.assign` I was able to make it work.

```js
const a = {
  b: {
    c: "new object",
    b: {
      c: "new object",
    }
  }
}

let currentObj = a;
// checking if "b" is present in the object and nesting if present
while (currentObj["b"]) {
  currentObj = currentObj["b"];
}
// adding the new object once b is not present
currentObj["b"] = {
  c: "new object"
}
```